How does MyPy work when considering MagicMock
I was thinking about enabling the same mypy rules in my tests as in my production code. I started doing some tinkering in mypy playground and found some things I do not quite understand about how mypy and MagicMock play together. Let's say I have the following class:
class A:
    def method(self, variable: int) -> None:
        print("Hey!")

Now, I want to create a mock of that class on another test, so I would do something like this:
mock = MagicMock(spec_set=A)

Because I have used spec_set if I try to do something like:
mock.not_existing.return_value = "Meh"

Then I will get a runtime error, but surprisingly (?) I will not get any error from mypy. This made me think that maybe mypy just ignored everything related to MagicMock. Then I tried something like:
def function(some: A) -> None:
    print(some)
    
# no mypy error either
function(mock)

Again, it does not trigger any mypy error, which I guess it's the expected behavior because that mock is mocking A. Nonetheless, if you change it to:
class B:
    def method_2(self, variable: int) -> None:
        print("Hey!")
        

mock_2 = MagicMock(spec_set=B)
function(mock_2)

Then, no mypy error either. I also tried the following:
mock: A = MagicMock(spec_set=A)
mock.not_existing.something() # runtime and mypy error
mock.method.return_value = 1 # mypy error due to return_value not existing

So, is there any way to change this behavior? Without this, I'm not sure if it makes sense to add mypy to my tests because I would be getting false negatives I guess.
As a bonus part of the question, I also thought about this:
mock.method.return_value = "Meh"

Which does not trigger any error (runtime or from mypy). Ideally, it should throw both, because I'm breaking the spec (so I guess spec_set should do something about it) and also because I'm not returning None, as the type hint suggests.
Here you can test the same example in mypy playground

From typeshed:
# We subclass with "Any" because mocks are explicitly designed to stand in for other types,
# something that can't be expressed with our static type system.
class NonCallableMock(Base, Any):

Type checkers look at this stub file, see Any as a superclass of NonCallableMock, and effectively disable most type checking for all instances of this class. That includes instances of MagicMock, which is a descendant of NonCallableMock.

Glad to know the reason, thanks! The question was more aimed at to know how to actually overcome this and improve type safety in my tests.

@AntonioGamizDelgado: Mocks are just way too dynamic for mypy to handle any better than this.

Mocks are convenient precisely because they're so dynamic, but anything you can do with a mock, you can do with a statically defined class.  In your case you could define subclasses of A and B that implement your mock behavior if you wanted them to be typecheckable.  If you use protocols in the code under test, you don't even need subclasses in the test.
